# Excel Macro- Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range (within For Loop to copy)

Tags: excel, vba

This is a simple macro code to copy range A2 until last row from one workbook and paste the same in another workbook. I am a newbie and googled many pages but failed to help self. The code is pasted below-

`

```
Sub TC_Creation_Sample()
Dim aPath As String, aFile As String, bFile As String
Dim FinalRow As Integer, x As Integer

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
End With

aPath = "C:\temp\"
aFile = aPath & "Config"
bFile = aPath & "TC_Template"
Workbooks.Open (aFile)
Sheets("Config").Activate
'FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
FinalRow = Worksheets("Config").Range("A2").End(xlDown)

For x = 2 To FinalRow
            Worksheets("Config").Range("A" & x).Select
            Selection.Copy
            Workbooks.Open (bFile)
            Worksheets("TestCases").Range("A" & x).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
Next x       
End Sub
```

`

Result- Upon debugging, it's found that the code is successfully copy pasting A2 value. However, it's throwing run-time error 9: Subscript out of range. And the error occurs when Worksheets("Config").Range("A" & x).Select is running for the second time after Next x. I am not sure what's really causing this error. Kindly, advise.

Comment: It looks like you are performing tasks many times which should only be performed once... like opening a workbook. And also - try to take full range and paste it rather than looping through one by one

Comment: **For loop** is implemented as there's a need to look at the data getting pasted one record cell after another in a column vertically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this any better? I assigned your `workbooks` to `workbook variables` and took out `select` and `copy` methods. I also added `.Row` as others have also suggested

```
Sub TC_Creation_Sample()
    Dim aPath As String, aFile As String, bFile As String
    Dim FinalRow As Long, x As Long
    Dim wbA As Workbook, wbB As Workbook

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
    End With

    aPath = "C:\temp\"
    aFile = aPath & "Config"
    bFile = aPath & "TC_Template"

    Set wbA = Workbook.Open(aFile)
    Set wbB = Workbooks.Open(bFile)

    FinalRow = wbA.Worksheets("Config").Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
    'FinalRow = wbA.Worksheets("Config").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For x = 2 To FinalRow
        wbB.Worksheets("TestCases").Range("A" & x).Value = wbA.Worksheets("Config").Range("A" & x)
    Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: @CallumDA- Thank you for the suggestion which not only solved the problem but is easily understood! Additionally, the FinalRow and x are changed to Long.

Comment: Happy to help, if this solved your problem please accept the answer by clicking the tick mark to the left of this answer

Answer (score 1):

You haven't assigned row number to `FinalRow` variable. Try:

```
FinalRow = Worksheets("Config").Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
```

Comment: Tried with adding .Row, but same error is encountered at the same position in the second run of for loop

Answer (score 1):

A number of points to mention.

First - An Excel workbook can contain many millions of rows - but your code is being limited to only 32,768 rows, because you are defining both **FinalRow** and **X** as Integers.  Use Long Integers instead (Dim X as Long, FinalRow as Long), in case one of the workbooks you open has more than 32,000 rows.

Now onto the cause of the error.  When you run the code for the second time through the For-Next Loop, the system hangs, because as far as it's concerned, the active workbook is bFile, and because Config tab doesn't exist on bFile (it's on aFile), it crashes with the unhelpful error message you get (because it can't find the right tab, because it's looking in the wrong place).

Incidentally, your code will attempt to open (bFile) EVERY time the For..Next loop triggers.  Do you need to open the file every time?  Surely it's just a case of copying the details from one sheet to the next?

You should also have some error handling.  If either aFile doesn't contain Config tab, or bFile doesn't contain TestCases tab, the code will crash out.  I would strongly recommend that you some error handling in to handles these instances.